# How to submit custom fields data by python wordpress xmlrpc

Tags: python-3.x, wordpress, xml-rpc

I use wp job manager on my website. when I tried to add listing by xmlrpc, everything is fine, but Categories and Location are empty.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TJJn.jpg)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTOkV.jpg)

My code is as below. Could you tell me what's wrong with my code?
Thanks

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import posts
from wordpress_xmlrpc import WordPressTerm
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import taxonomies

wp = Client('http://127.0.0.1/15wp/xmlrpc.php', 'admin', '123456')

# now let's create a new product
widget = WordPressPost()
widget.post_type = 'job_listing'
widget.title = 'Widgetlast02'
widget.content = 'This is the widgets description.'
widget.post_status = 'publish'
widget.custom_fields = []
widget.custom_fields.append({
        'job_location': 'Newyork',
        'job_listing_category':  'hotel'
})
widget.id = wp.call(posts.NewPost(widget))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `custom_fields` attribute expects a list of dicts.

Within each dict, it expects values for `key` and `value` fields.

Here, `key` is the name of the custom field, and `value` is the value you want to assign to it.

Below is the snippet for your specific example.

```
widget.custom_fields = [
    {
        'key': 'job_location',
        'value':  'Newyork'
    }, 
    {
        'key': 'job_listing_category',
        'value':  'hotel'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess from looking at the [documentation for `WordPressPost` in `wordpress_xmlrpc`](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/wordpress.html#wordpresspost):

*(Emphasis mine)*

> class WordPressPost
>
> Represents a post, page, or other registered custom post type in
>   WordPress.
>
> - id
> - user
> - date (datetime)
> - date_modified (datetime)
> - slug
> - post_status
> - title
> - content
> - excerpt
> - link
> - comment_status
> - ping_status
> - terms (list of WordPressTerms)
> - terms_names (dict)
> - **custom_fields (dict)**
> - enclosure (dict)
> - password
> - post_format
> - thumbnail
> - sticky
> - post_type

It expects `custom_fields` to be a `dict` - you're creating a `list` and then inserting a `dict` into that list:

```
widget.custom_fields = []
widget.custom_fields.append({
        'job_location': 'Newyork',
        'job_listing_category':  'hotel'
})
```

This will probably work better:

```
widget.custom_fields = {
        'job_location': 'Newyork',
        'job_listing_category':  'hotel'
}
```

Comment: hi, it still doesn't work.  I referred to this page:https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/posts.html#custom-post-types